# QML StackView custom transition

Tags: qt, qml, transition, stackview

I have gone through the Qt docs :[Qt StackView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-stackview.html#completeTransition-method) yet still I can't figure out what am I doing wrong, because my code should produce fade in/out animation but what I got is just an instant blink between content. I hope my description is sufficient and clear.

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: StackViewDelegate {

        function transitionFinished(properties)
        {
            properties.exitItem.opacity = 1
        }

        property Component pushTransition: StackViewTransition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: enterItem
                property: "opacity"
                from: 0
                to: 1
                duration: 10
            }
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: exitItem
                property: "opacity"
                from: 1
                to: 0
                duration: 10
            }
        }
    }
    initialItem: Item {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ListView {
            model: pageModel
            anchors.fill: parent
            delegate: AndroidDelegate {
                text: title
                onClicked: stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(page))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hit the same problem and asked their support - their example is wrong.

replace

```
property Component pushTransition: StackViewTransition {
```

with

```
pushTransition: StackViewTransition {
```

and it should work. pushTransition is actually a property on [StackViewDelegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-stackviewdelegate.html#transitionFinished-method)

I'm still trying to get the transitionFinished function to work becuase their example of that doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually, I find transitionFinished working in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me:

```
Window {
    id: mainWindowId
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    StackView {
       id: stackViewId
       anchors.fill: parent

      replaceEnter: Transition {
          PropertyAnimation{
              property: "opacity"
              from: 0
              to: 1
              duration: 300
          }
      }

      replaceExit: Transition {
          PropertyAnimation{
              property: "opacity"
              from: 1
              to: 0
              duration: 250
          }
      }

      initialItem: "yourStartingPage.qml"

    }
}
```

And for changing views:

```
stackViewId.replace("yourOtherPage.qml")
```

Answer (score 1):

The duration of your animation is 10 milliseconds, or 1/100th of a second.

Comment: Well, I tried different values: 1k, 10k, 100k still no result